# How to avoid graph duplication when using tf.import_graph_def to append a new input pipeline?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to have two different pipelines for a model I am doing in tensorflow. To achieve this, I have taken answers from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1758) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364377/how-to-replace-the-input-of-a-saved-graph-e-g-a-placeholder-by-a-dataset-itera), but each time I run it and save the graph to display it in tensorboard, or print all the nodes available in the graph, it shows that the original model has been duplicated instead of appending a new input to the corresponding node.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Creates toy dataset with tf.data API
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random_uniform([4, 10]))
dataset = dataset.batch(32)

# Input placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10],name='x')

# Main model
with tf.variable_scope('model'):
    y = tf.add(tf.constant(2.),x,name='y')
    z = tf.add(tf.constant(2.),y,name='z')

# Session
sess = tf.Session()

# Iterator that will be the new input pipeline for training
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_elem = iterator.get_next()

graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()

# If uncommented, it creates an error
#tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create the input to the node y
x_ds = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def=graph_def,
    input_map={'x:0':next_elem})

# Write to disk the graph
tf.summary.FileWriter('./',sess.graph)

# Print all the nodes names
for node in sess.graph_def.node:
    print(node.name)
```

I would expect only one y and z node. However, when displaying all the names of the graph or checking it with tensorboard there are two structures, the original, and other within the 'import' namespace with the dataset input to y. Any idea how to solve this? Or is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Sometimes it happens when you give the wrong path, like in writing the graph to disk section. It happened to me due to that, so I m just mentioning it here, I don't know how relevant it is to your exact problem, but it can help others trying to debug this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some other questions I found the answer to my problem.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748552/tensorflow-how-to-replace-a-node-in-a-calculation-graph) is a fantastic explanation on how to join nodes from different graphs.

The key here is to manually define the graph where each op will be created. Take the next code has an example.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

### Main model with a placeholder as input

# Create a graph
g_1 = tf.Graph()

# Define everything inside it
with g_1.as_default():
    # Input placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=[None,2],name='x')
    with tf.variable_scope('model'):
        y = tf.add(tf.constant(2.,dtype=tf.float64),x,name='y')
        z = tf.add(tf.constant(2.,dtype=tf.float64),y,name='z')

gdef_1 = g_1.as_graph_def()


### Change the input pipeline

# Create another graph
g_2 = tf.Graph()

# Define everything inside it
with g_2.as_default():
    # Create a toy tf.dataset 
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.array([[1.,2],[3,4],[5,6]]))
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)

    # Iterator that will be the new input pipeline for training
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_elem = iterator.get_next()
    # Create an identical operation as next_elemebt with name so it can be
    # manipulated later
    next_elem = tf.identity(next_elem,name='next_elem') 

    # Create the new pipeline. Use next_elem as input instead of x
    z, = tf.import_graph_def(gdef_1,
        input_map={'x:0':next_elem},
        return_elements=['model/z:0'],
        name='') # Set name to '' so it conserves the same scope as the original

# Create session linked to g_1
sess_1 = tf.Session(graph=g_1)

# Create session linked to g_2
sess_2 = tf.Session(graph=g_2)

# Initialize the iterator
sess_2.run(iterator.initializer)

# Write the graph to disk
tf.summary.FileWriter('./',sess_2.graph)

# Testing placeholders
out = sess_1.run([y],feed_dict={x:np.array([[1.,2.]],dtype=np.float64)})
print(out)

# Testing tf.data
out = sess_2.run([z])
print(out)
```

Now, everything should be in a different graph.